# Laravel post detected as method not allowed and forbidden

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, tinymce

I had this issue where I would get a method not allowed exception even though the route were set as `Route::post` and the server returned a **403** code and not detecting any form input. What should I do to get the method accepted properly as POST and can receive any form input?

Form

```
<form data-role="none" method="post" data-ajax="false" action="http://www.example.com/sell/details/save">

                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="title">

                        Product Descriptions /<br>

                        Additional Pictures /<br>

                        Video

                    </div>

                    <div class="control">

                            <div id="mceu_4" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="application" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px;"><div id="mceu_4-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout"><div id="mceu_5" class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group"><div id="mceu_5-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout"><div id="mceu_6" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-first mce-last" role="toolbar"><div id="mceu_6-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout"><div id="mceu_7" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_7-body"><div id="mceu_0" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_0" role="button" aria-label="Bold"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bold"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_1" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_1" role="button" aria-label="Bullet list"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bullist"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_2" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_2" role="button" aria-label="Insert/edit video"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-media"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_3" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_3" role="button" aria-label="Upload an image"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-image"></i>Upload</button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="mceu_8" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"><iframe id="text-description_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" src='javascript:""' style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display: block;"></iframe></div><div id="mceu_9" class="mce-statusbar mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"><div id="mceu_9-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout"><div id="mceu_10" class="mce-path mce-flow-layout-item mce-first"><div role="button" class="mce-path-item mce-last" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_10-0" aria-level="0">p</div></div><label id="mceu_12" class="mce-wordcount mce-widget mce-label mce-flow-layout-item">Words: 0</label><div id="mceu_11" class="mce-flow-layout-item mce-resizehandle mce-last"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-resize"></i></div></div></div></div></div><textarea class="input-gradient control-row" data-role="none" name="text-description" id="text-description" height="200" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></textarea>



                        <div class="caption-bold caption">

                            Add in additional details of your products (i.e. functions, specifications,

                            etc.) and also pictures / video to make your sale item more attractive

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- .form-row -->

                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="title">Product Variations (if any)</div>

                    <div class="control" id="wrapper-variation">

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <div class="caption-bold caption">

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" id="btn-add-more"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add More

                                </button>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" id="total_qty" value="10">


                        <div class="control-row">

                            <input type="text" class="input-gradient input-mobile" data-role="none" name="text-variation[0]" placeholder="Variation" value="">

                            <div class="caption caption-side">Qty</div>

                        <input type="text" class="promo input-gradient variation-qty" data-role="none" name="text-variation-qty[0]" placeholder="Qty" value="">

                        </div>




                    </div>

                    <div class="title"></div>

                    <div class="control">

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <div class="notice notice-check"></div>

                            <div class="notice notice-qty"></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- .form-row -->

                <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="title">Delivery Method</div>

                    <div class="control">


                        <div class="control-row">

                            <input id="check-delivery" data-role="none" type="checkbox" name="check-delivery" value="1" class="input-gradient">

                            <label for="check-delivery" id="label-ig">Normal Postage

                            </label>

                            <input type="text" class="promo input-gradient" data-role="none" name="postage-fee" id="postage-fee" style="margin-left:4px;width:150px;" value="" placeholder="Set Cost">

                            <div class="notice"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <label id="label-ig" for="qty-postage-fee">

                                Adjust Postage Fee by Incremental Qty of

                            </label>

                            <input type="text" class="promo input-gradient" data-role="none" name="qty-postage-fee" id="qty-postage-fee" placeholder="Qty" value="">

                        </div>

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <div>

                                <p>Example: Postage Fee $1</p>



                                <p>

                                    By choosing an incremental qty of 5pcs, the cost of shipping

                                    1-5pcs will be $1. Subsequent 5 pcs will cost

                                    another $1, as such, the total of 10pcs would be $2.

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <input id="check-registered-mail" data-role="none" type="checkbox" name="check-registered-mail" value="1" class="input-gradient">

                            <label for="check-registered-mail" id="label-ig">Registered Mail</label>

                            <input type="text" class="promo input-gradient" data-role="none" name="mail-fee" id="mail-fee" style="margin-left:4px;width:150px;" value="" placeholder="Add. Cost">

                            <div class="notice"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="control-row">

                            <input id="check-self-col" data-role="none" type="checkbox" name="check-self-col" value="1" class="input-gradient">

                            <label for="check-self-col" id="label-ig">Self Collection</label>

                            <input type="text" class="promo input-gradient" data-role="none" name="self-location" id="self-location" style="margin-left:4px;width:250px;" value="" placeholder="Location">

                            <div class="notice"></div>



                        </div>



                        <div class="caption-bold caption">

                            Seller contact buyers directly to arrange pick-up at designated date,

                            time and location after the deal is confirmed.

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-row" style="text-align : center;">

                    <input type="submit" value="Save &amp; Continue" class="btn btn-form-pro">

                    <!-- the following button is only for demo but the commented submit button above is the original one-->

                    <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-form-pro btn-pop" id="btn-save-details">Save & Continue

                    </button-->

                </div>

            </form>
```

The controller, simply just dump out the form data.

```
public function save()
{
var_dump(Input::all());
}
```

The route.

```
Route::post('/sell/details/save', 'SellDetailsController@save');
```

The textarea have an upload image feature, and is powered with tinymce + jboil.me plugin. **The issue only occurs when the tinymce have an image uploaded on it, so when inputing a text only data inside tinymce editor, it would works normally**.

So,

1. Input without image, everything works fine.
2. Input with image, method not allowed occurs and no form data in Input::all().
3. Input with image, with `Route::any` instead of `Route::post`, forbidden returned and no form data.

How can I fix this and have both image and non image input works correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the image upload work properly (does the image show up in your tinymce textarea)?

Comment: The image is replaced with a dummy image during editing, only later when the textarea content is rendered as html (displaying the record), it will be replaced with the real image. The image is uploaded, checked on the server side with FTP and it is there.

Answer (score 0):

you have set the "Route:post" but you have set the method in form as GET.
so the method is not allowing. Try making the route method and form method same.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly copied a code that I messed up when trying using GET, I changed it back to POST.

Answer (score -1):

As TinyMCE will add an input type file, you should add an enctype attribute to your form :

```
<form [...] enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If the form tag is generated through Laravel, then use this :

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'/sell/details/save','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
```

Comment: The files are uploaded separately by **jboil.me**, so when the user upload the image it will be uploaded first and the textarea would have a `<img src="/uploaded_image"/>` content on it. So the form that posted to the `save` method doesn't actually contains any file inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line inside your html form.

```
<input type="hidden" _token="{{ csrf_token }}" />
```